# spring automatic bean definition from library/jar file

Tags: spring

I'm writing a library that contains some utility classes, is there an idiomatic spring way to let the library/jar file define beans automatically?

The library will be included in several spring application, but I don't want to register the utility beans in all spring applications that are using my helper library.
so it it possible that a library/jar file defines beans for itself and all using spring application automatically add those beans to their context?

Answer (score 0):

You can group your beans based on the utilities/packages and then define them in

> @Configuration

classes.

for e.g.

Class A and Class B are in package com.example.helper and similarly 
Class X and Class Y are in package com.example.utilities

you can create 2 Configuration classes in each package and define the beans

```
@Configuration
public class HelperConfiguration{
 @Bean
 public A a(){
   return new A();
 }
}
```

and similarly in package com.example.utilities create

```
@Configuration
public class UtilitiesConfiguration{
 @Bean
 public X x(){
   return new X();
 }
}
```

now if your client spring application only need beans from utilities package they can simply import UtilitiesConfiguration class.

```
@Import({ UtilitiesConfiguration.class})
public class ClientApp{
  ...
}
```

This way you can modularise your code.